# Wordpress local file permissions

Tags: wordpress

I have a local install of wordpress.

I am having a nightmare setting the the permissions right.

If it set it all to 777 it errors 500, I have i set it 644 but still the same!

What exactly are the right settings under apache2

Comment: I don't know them by heart, but try this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/websitedefender-wordpress-security/ It shows you your current chmod and tells you it that's a problem.

Comment: only issue with that is I can even load root at the mo so cant access wp-admin!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I`m developing wp plugins for a long time now and I`ve never seen Internal Error 500 on 777 permissions. It might be a good idea to give us more detail about your server configuration.
Giving you an answer about the permissions is kind of complicated, because it differs from server to server, but generally I use it as follows:

```
wp-admin 755 
wp-includes 755 
wp-content 755 
wp-content/images 777 
.htaccess 644 
wp-admin/index.php 644 
wp-content/themes/your-theme/files 666 
wp-config.php 640 
Other files 640
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really nice to actually find what the right ones should be. I was also falling short of a apache not out putting errors to screen just saying 500 error, which was slowing me down a lot! Lesson: always have tail -f on the apache log!

Comment: [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=CONFIG) will 500 for perms that don't meet the configured umask under public_html

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a local version, have your tried setting your **whole wordpress folder** to permission 777? What operating system are you using? I used to get this under Ubuntu. Have your tried adding a simple php file to test if the link you're using is good?

Replying your question about permission: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress and http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-file-permissions will help you.